How to find subgame-perfect Nash Equilibria of this game?

I tried to solve this problem by working bottom-up i.e. from the rightmost node, with my thinking as follows:
Player 3 prefers 15 to 8 so chooses F. Now Player 2 prefers 7 to 5 so chooses option N. Now Player 1 prefers 7 to 5 so chooses option P. Am I  correct that the option set for player 3 is now between 8 at B or 1 at J so chooses B. So player 2 now chooses between 2 at D and 8 at A so chooses A and player 1 now chooses between 3 at S and 5 at C so chooses C?
So how do I write a strategy for the players that encapsulates that SPNE?
Thanks,

A strategy simply specifies what every player does at each information set (gere, simply the decision nodes). You have figured that out. What more do you want?
